# Reduce $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x-y+7}{2x+y-1}$ to a homogenous equation by substituting $x=X-1$ and $y=Y+3$

Tags: integration

> By substituting $x=X-1$ and $y=Y+3$ reduce the differential equation
>   $$
> \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x-y+7}{2x+y-1}
> $$
>   to a homogeneous equation and hence find the general solution in terms of $x$ and $y$.

All I have so far is:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4X-Y}{2X+Y}
$$

Then I thought about doing something like:

$$
X=x+1\\
dX=dx
$$

But I wasn't sure whether that was correct or useful here. Can somebody help point me in the right direction? The answer listed is $(y-x-4)^3(y+4x+1)^2=A$ where $|A|=e^c$.

Comment: divide both numerator and denominator of RHS by $X$, let $u=Y/X$

Comment: $\dfrac{dY}{dX}=\dfrac{4X-Y}{2X+Y}$ is "homogeneous" in the sense that the two constant terms are no longer there.  (But maybe that's not what was meant.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Thanks, but I still can't arrive at that answer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{4X-Y}{2X+Y}= \frac{4 -\frac{Y}{X}}{2 + \frac{Y}{X}}.$$

So, let $V= Y/X$, so $Y=VX\implies dY/dX = V + X(dV/dX)$. With these, we substitute:

$$V + X\frac{dV}{dX} = \frac{4 -V}{2 +V}\implies \frac{2+V}{4-3V-V^2}dV = \frac{dX}{X}.$$

This can be broken up using partial fractions. After we will exploit the properties of logarithms to get an answer in the form of $$(1-V)^3(V+4)^2X^5=e^C.$$
Since $V=Y/X$, we substitute that back in, simplify, and then substitute $X=x+1$, and $Y=y-3$, and simplify again. It's more of an algebra exercise!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let:

$$Y = v X \implies \dfrac{dY}{dX} = v + X \dfrac{dv}{dX}$$

Substitute into your reduced equation.